# Extract Unique Records from Datasets in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dataset, record, unique-key

Here is a not quite difficult question, however because of the fact that I am still learning MATLAB, I have to admire that I am struggling a bit. Well, let's assume that we have two datasets:

```
Input1 = [
Date;X1;X2;X3
2007-06-19;2;1;3
2007-06-22;1;2;3
2007-06-01;1;2;3
2007-06-18;1;2;3
2007-06-19;1;2;3
2007-06-20;1;2;3
2007-06-25;1;2;3
]

Input2 = [
Date;X1;X2;X3
2007-06-22;1;2;3
2007-06-19;1;2;3
2007-06-25;2;1;3
2007-06-01;1;2;3
2007-06-15;1;2;3
2007-06-18;1;2;3
2007-06-21;1;2;3
2007-06-25;1;2;3
]

Output1 = [
]

Output2 = [
]
```

What I want to do is:
- Sort each of them separately based on the first column (where the oldest date is placed first).
- Delete duplicates in each file  separately based on the first column.
- Keep two lines (one for each dataset) if and only if their key exists in both these datasets.
- Do a final check to ensure that the date elements on both lists are the same one by one.

eualin.

Answer (score 3):

To get you started, you'll need to clean up your input data a bit before you can really unleash the power of Matlab.

First, lose the 'column headers', *ie* the lines `Date;X1;X2;X3`.  Matlab arrays are numeric, even Matlab character arrays are really numeric.

Second, put semi-colons only at the end of each row; as far as Matlab arrays are concerned a semi-colon IS the end of a row, so your tables threaten to become column vectors.  Use either spaces or commas where you currently have semi-colons and put a semi-colon at the end of each row.

Thirdly, Matlab arrays are numeric and something like 2007-06-22 ain't a number.  As you've written it it isn't something that Matlab will recognise as a string either.  And if it did recognise it as a string it would barf on the input because it's not all numeric.

You could work with cell arrays or structures but it's probably easier to turn your input arrays into numbers.  For example, evaluating the following expression:

```
Input1 = [
datenum(datevec('2007-06-19')),2,1,3;
datenum(datevec('2007-06-22')),1,2,3;
datenum(datevec('2007-06-01')),1,2,3;
datenum(datevec('2007-06-18')),1,2,3;
datenum(datevec('2007-06-19')),1,2,3;
datenum(datevec('2007-06-20')),1,2,3;
datenum(datevec('2007-06-25')),1,2,3;
]
```

will give you a nice numeric array to work on as Dan has already suggested.  `datenum` and `datevec` are functions built in to Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

To get you started, a sorted list without duplicates do this for each:

```
% find the unique values for the first column
[~, I] = unique(Input1(:,1));
% extract the records for each unique value in the first column (sorted)
SortedAndUnique = Input1(I,:);
```

I'm sure you will work out the rest

Comment: No, can you be specific? What doesn't work? Are you getting errors? Did you clean your data the way @High Performance Mark has suggested?

Comment: Exactly. I get the following message 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions.' What I have done already is to convert dates (first column) into numbers.

Comment: LET me change the question a bit. FORGET about the duplicates Could you please help me 1) sort each table based on each first column, and 2) update both tables simultaneously by keeping two certain records (one at each table) if and only if both of them contains the same key.

Comment: Hmmm... I think maybe the issue is unique should only be applied to the date column. See the edit above. Read up about unique, it sorts the data by default and the second output parameter, i.e. I in this case, provides an index map of how the original numbers moved into their new positions.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

- you can use `datenum('2007-06-22','yyyy-mm-dd')` to express your dates as numbers
- `unique()` as mentionend in Dan's answer
- `intersect()` to find keys that are both in Input1 and Input2

Comment: OK guys. Just managed to convert dates (first column) into numbers. Could you please give me a hint about the 2nd and 3rd step?

Comment: I already provided you with the second step. As for the third try type help intersect in the command line?

Comment: Hi Dan. Of course I see your answer. I just wanna ask if you could provide a bit more details, cause I don't understand I am afraid.

Comment: Unique applied to the first column gives you the indices of the unique values in this column. Use this information to extract all the rows that have a unique value in the first column. Do the same for the second dataset. The usage of intersect then is almost the same. Intersect the first column from dataset 1 with the first column of dataset 2 to find the indices of those values that appear in both (the indices won't be the same for the two columns). Again use the indices to extract the corresponding rows in each set. Datenum, unique and intersect along with basic indexing is all you need.